# When using the mozilla firefox sdk, how do you access Request in a worker script?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to be able to send out a request from my plugin (with the cookies of the page)

```
var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var widget = widgets.Widget({
id: "mozilla-link",
label: "Mozilla website",
contentURL: "http://www.favicon.cc/logo3d/33101.png",
onClick: function () {
    var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: self.data.url('scanner.js')

    });

    worker.port.emit('scanner');
 }
});
```

and the worker script

```
self.port.on("scanner", function () {
var http = Request({ url:'..', onComplete: function(Response) {}}).get();
 });
```

but I am told that request is not defined... even if i try to define it in the worker script.

```
ReferenceError: Request is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

page workers are just like any other web page, so in the worker you would use xmlhttprequest. if you want to use request, you must do so in your addon's main.js file. If you want to make cross-domain requests, you will need to set the permissions property in your package.json file:

https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/doc/dev-guide-source/guides/content-scripts/cross-domain.md

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem as I want to do a cross domain request.

Comment: you can do cross-domain requests to specific urls in the current version of the SDK. Tee these docs from github for more detail on how to set this up: https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/doc/dev-guide-source/package-spec.md

Comment: You still don't understand. I want to do the cross domain requests in my worker script to report back. I don't want to do them in my main script.

Comment: The permissions property in package.json should allow you to do this, see these other docs: https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/doc/dev-guide-source/guides/content-scripts/cross-domain.md